# py-cpuinfo returning absolutely no information. (py-cpuinfo 9.0.0)

Tags: python, pip

So I've been expirimenting with [py-cpuinfo](https://pypi.org/project/py-cpuinfo/) and realized that the latest version, on my computer, seems to completely and fully deny me any possibility of using the module at all. What occurs is that when using cpuinfo.get_cpu_info() it returns a blank dictionary (Ie. {}). The following snipet is something that continues to occur with the same result.

```
from py-cpuinfo import get_cpu_info
info = get_cpu_info()

print(info)
```

I attempted to restart my computer and even go through many different documentations and example programs to try and get the library to work properly.

Comment: report an issue? https://github.com/workhorsy/py-cpuinfo/issues